# Use datetime.strftime() on years before 1900? ("require year >= 1900")

Tags: python, datetime, strftime

I used :
`utctime = datetime.datetime(1601,1,1) + datetime.timedelta(microseconds = tup[5])
 last_visit_time = "Last visit time:"+ utctime.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')`

But I have the time of 1601, so the error show:
`ValueError: year=1601 is before 1900; the datetime strftime() methods require year >= 1900`

I used python2.7, how can I make it? Thanks a lot!

Comment: You will need an external library.  mxDateTime does dates back to year 0.  http://www.egenix.com/products/python/mxBase/mxDateTime/doc/

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
>>> utctime.isoformat()
'1601-01-01T00:00:00.000050'
```

Now if you want to have exactly the same format as above:

```
iso = utctime.isoformat()
tokens = iso.strip().split("T")
last_visit_time = "Last visit time: %s %s" % (tokens[0], tokens[1].strip().split(".")[0])
```

Not that there seems to be a patch for `strftime` to fix this behavior [here](http://bugs.python.org/file10253/strftime-pre-1900.patch) (not tested)

Answer (score 14):

the `isoformat` method accepts a parameter specifing the character(s) dividing the date part from the time part of a datetime obj in its representation. Therefore:

```
>>> utctime.isoformat(" ")
'1601-01-01 00:00:00.000050'
```

should do it.
Furthermore, if you want to remove the microseconds you can operate a split.

```
>>> utctime.isoformat(" ").split(".")[0]
'1601-01-01 00:00:00'
```

Answer (score 12):

There are various ways to alter `strftime` so that it handles pre-1900 dates:

- There's a [recipe at ASPN](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/306860-proleptic-gregorian-dates-and-strftime-before-1900/) that gives you a separate `strftime` method that you can call with a date object: `aspn_recipe.strftime(dt, fmt)` if you set it up in a module yourself
- As [@stephen-rumbalski said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10263956/use-datetime-strftime-on-years-before-1900-require-year-1900/32206673#comment13197466_10263956), the external [mxDateTime](http://www.egenix.com/products/python/mxBase/mxDateTime/doc/) package supports this; but that's using a totally different date object system
- As of version `1.5`, the [virtualtime](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualtime) package will patch both `time.strftime` and `datetime.datetime.strftime` to behave as in Python `3.3`+. You can take advantage of this without enabling the other virtual time functions. (*Disclaimer: I work on this package*)

Note that Python `2.7`, `3.0` and `3.1` have errors before the year 1900, Python `3.2` has errors before the year 1000. Additionally, pre-`3.2` versions interpret years between `0` and `99` as between `1969` and `2068`. Python versions from `3.3` onward support all positive years in `datetime` (and negative years in `time.strftime`), and `time.strftime` doesn't do any mapping of years between `0` and `99`.

The original [Python bug](http://bugs.python.org/issue1777412) explains that they decided that this was a feature in Python 2.7 (presumably since it avoided lack of system `strftime` support for these dates), and then gradually worked on it in the Python 3 series, by reimplementing functionality.

Comment: I tried the virtualtime monkeypatcher, but I can't find any documentation and I can't figure out what i need to do to make it go.

Comment: I used `sudo pip install virtualtime` to install it, then imported it with `import virtualtime` and called `virtualtime.enable()`. Worked great!

Comment: virtualtime saved the day

Comment: I tried the `import virtualtime` / `virtualtime.enable()` approach.  For reasons I don't entirely understand, it made all the `DateTimeField`s in my Django models save only the date and not the time in Postgres.  virtuatime 1.6, Django 1.11.13.

Answer (score 8):

I recommend using [arrow](https://arrow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) (which is an abstraction package on datetime and dateutil), it's really easy to handle every kind of datetime objects, even in Python 2.6/7.x and with dates prior to 1900.

For example:

```
>>> import arrow

>>> in_date_str = "1853-10-30T13:36:41.942623+00:00"
>>> in_date_obj = arrow.get(crea)
>>> print(in_date_obj)
arrow[1853-10-30T13:36:41.942623+00:00]>

# basic formatting
>>> in_date_obj.format()
u'1853-10-30 13:36:41-00:00'

# advanced formatting
>>> in_date_obj.format("dddd D MMMM YYYY", "fr_FR")
u'Dimanche 30 Octobre 1853'

# humanized delta
>>> in_date_obj.humanize()
u'162 years ago'
# easy localization handling
>>> in_date_obj.humanize(locale="fr_FR")
u'il y a 162 ans'
```