# Unable to read data from BigQuery when a timestamp column contains year < 1900

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

On a pipeline defined using the latest Apache Beam SDK for Python 2.2.0, I get this error when running a simple pipeline that reads and writes a BigQuery table.

Since a few rows have timestamps with year < 1900, the read operation fails. How can I patch this dataflow_worker package?

```
apache_beam.runners.dataflow.dataflow_runner.DataflowRuntimeException: Dataflow pipeline failed. State: FAILED, Error:
(4d31192aa4aec063): Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dataflow_worker/batchworker.py", line 582, in do_work
    work_executor.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dataflow_worker/executor.py", line 167, in execute
    op.start()
  File "dataflow_worker/native_operations.py", line 38, in dataflow_worker.native_operations.NativeReadOperation.start
    def start(self):
  File "dataflow_worker/native_operations.py", line 39, in dataflow_worker.native_operations.NativeReadOperation.start
    with self.scoped_start_state:
  File "dataflow_worker/native_operations.py", line 44, in dataflow_worker.native_operations.NativeReadOperation.start
    with self.spec.source.reader() as reader:
  File "dataflow_worker/native_operations.py", line 48, in dataflow_worker.native_operations.NativeReadOperation.start
    for value in reader:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dataflow_worker/nativefileio.py", line 198, in __iter__
    for record in self.read_next_block():
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dataflow_worker/nativeavroio.py", line 95, in read_next_block
    yield self.decode_record(record)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dataflow_worker/nativebigqueryavroio.py", line 110, in decode_record
    record, self.source.table_schema)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dataflow_worker/nativebigqueryavroio.py", line 104, in _fix_field_values
    record[field.name], field)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dataflow_worker/nativebigqueryavroio.py", line 83, in _fix_field_value
    return dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f UTC')
ValueError: year=200 is before 1900; the datetime strftime() methods require year >= 1900
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot patch it to work with timestamps because that is the internal implementation of Google's Apache Beam runner: Dataflow. So you will have to wait until this is fixed by Google (should this be identified as a bug). Please, report it as soon as possible because this is more a limitation of Python's version used rather than a bug.

The problem comes from `strftime` as you can see in the error. The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) explicitly mentions it won't work with any year prior to 1900.
A workaround, on your end though, is to convert the timestamp to a string (you can do this in BigQuery as specified in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#conversion-rules)). And then in your Beam pipeline you can reconvert it again to some timestamp or whatever suits you best.

You also have an example on how to convert a `datetime`object to a string as the template of your error in [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10264070). In the same question there is another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32206673) that explains what has happened with this bug and how has it been solved (in Python) and what you can do. Unfortunately, the solution seems to avoid using `strftime` at all, and use some alternative instead.