# How to parse dates with years prior to 1000 with dateparser?

Tags: python, datetime

I am trying to use `dateparser` to parse dates with years earlier that 1000, with less than four digits.

```
import dateparser

value = "july 900"
result = dateparser.parse(value)
result is None  # True
```

At first I thought is related to the problem mentioned here: [Use datetime.strftime() on years before 1900? ("require year >= 1900")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10263956/use-datetime-strftime-on-years-before-1900-require-year-1900), because some of the times with certain inputs (like just `900`) the result was the current day and month combined with the year `1900`.
But after some more trials with random dates and relative expressions, I noticed `dateparser` can output dates earlier than `1000`, then I figured out that if I zero-pad the year, the result will be correct.

```
import dateparser

value = "july 0900"
result = dateparser.parse(value)
result is None  # False
result  # datetime.datetime(900, 7, 4, 0, 0)
```

I have found this in my search for a solution:
https://github.com/scrapinghub/dateparser/issues/410
but the final comment left me with more questions than answers, as I have failed to find a way to pass a custom parser to the internal user of `dateutil.parser` of `dateparser`.

My current solution is to look for regex 3 digits year patterns, using something similar to this: `(.* +| *|.+[\/\-.]{1,})([1-9][0-9]{2,})( *| +.*|[\/\-.]{1,}.+)` and pad them in place.

Is there a better way to do this?

**EDIT:**

Is there also an elegant solution to parse dates before our era (e.g. BC)? (it seems that the `dateparser` settings key `SUPPORT_BEFORE_COMMON_ERA` doesn't do much in this regard, and all other seemed to be unrelated)

So that this can be used for an archeological dating site.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use regular expressions with dates. It is hard and the corner cases will drive you nuts. The module `dateutil` does what you want correctly.

```
>>> from dateutil import parser
>>> value = "july 900"
>>> parser.parse(value)
datetime.datetime(900, 7, 4, 0, 0)
```

This is not a solution for dates before the current era. That is because `dateutil` and `dateparser` both work with `datetime`s and `datetime`s don't accept years less than 1.

Comment: Yes, that would solve part of the problem, but I do need to use the `dateparser` library, which doesn't seem to provide hooks for me to meddle with it.

Comment: In that case your best bet would be to report this issue as a bug to the `dateparser` maintainers. The module claims to parse "localized dates in almost any string formats commonly found on web pages" and I think "July 900" should qualify.

Comment: That seems the most reasonable course of action, and I will do it. Though I was hoping someone else encountered this problem and found a solution outside the library's code.